# Populating google map with markers JSON

Tags: javascript, php, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to populate a google map with markers. The information for each marker is contained in this array:

```
[{"id":"1","name":"toler","lng":"110.33929824829102","lat":"-7.779369982234709","created_at":"2014-02-21 16:19:28","updated_at":"2014-02-21 16:19:28"},{"id":"2","name":"hallo :)","lng":"110.36865234375","lat":"-7.797738383377609","created_at":"2014-02-21 16:19:49","updated_at":"2014-02-21 16:19:49"}]
```

However, my map does not show the markers. I am using this code in my javascript:

```
getLocations();

 function getLocations() {

   alert('hello');
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost:8888/public/test",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(json){
            $.each(json, function(i, entry){
                PlotMarker(json[i].lat, json[i].long);
            });
        },
        error: function(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
}

function PlotMarker(lat, long){
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long),
        map: map,
        draggable: false,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
    });
    markerLocations.push(marker);
}
```

Is there any way to fix this issue? Calling this url

```
http://localhost:8888/public/test
```

returns the JSON shown above.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

EDIT:

```
function initialize() {

var markers = [];
var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-7.8,110.3666667);
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
zoom: 13,
center: latLng,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

}
```

Comment: Where is `gmap` declared?

Comment: You mean the initialize function?

Comment: If you've declared `gmap` in `initialize` with `var` then other functions won't be able to see it. Declare `gmap` outside the function like: `var gmap` and then inside `initialize` just do `gmap = whatever`.

Comment: If I extract this variable out, my map is not shown anymore.

Comment: [Like this?](http://jsfiddle.net/8ZGqM/)

Comment: Yeah, from your updated question, `map` is local to initialize. The other functions can't see it.

Comment: What javascript errors are you getting?  I would expect they would explain the problem.

Comment: I do not get any. Here is a jsfiddle with all the code I am using. http://jsfiddle.net/676FY/1/

Comment: @geocodezip I have tried that and it does not work.

Comment: The javascript console doesn't work?  Or you don't get any errors?  Or you don't understand the errors you get?  Your fiddle has an error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined (index):142`; you aren't including the API.

Comment: If I go to developer tools in Safari and open the console I don't get any errors.

Comment: @geocodezip please have a look at this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/676FY/1/

Comment: [Here is one](http://jsfiddle.net/676FY/2/) that includes the API and JQuery and displays two obvious errors in Chrome: `Failed to load resource http://localhost:8888/public/test?callback=jQuery110109512475479859859_1393002050253&_=1393002050254`,`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'SearchBox' of undefined (index):42`

Comment: [Here is one that includes the places library](http://jsfiddle.net/676FY/3/) (which fixes the 'SearchBox' error), can't do anything about localhost not being available...

Comment: :( still, those two versions do not work.

Comment: Maybe there is some example json array that could be used here if localhost is not available.

Answer (score 2):

Declare your map variable *outside* of the `initialize` function. It's the only way that other functions will be able to see it:

```
var map;
function initialize() {
  var markers = [];
  var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-7.8,110.3666667);
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    zoom: 13,
    center: latLng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
}
```

Comment: Put all your code in a jsFiddle and I'll take a squiz.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/676FY/1/ here is my complete js code. Most of those function are there to give the user the possibility to save a new spot to a database.

Comment: You're redeclaring `map` again in `initialize`. It should just be `map = new google.maps.Map(...` not `var map = new google.maps.Map(...`

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle with the complete code besides the json array. http://jsfiddle.net/676FY/3/

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

`PlotMarker(entry.location.lat, entry.location.lng);`

to:

`PlotMarker(entry.lat, entry.lng);`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
PlotMarker(entry.location.lat, entry.location.lng);
```

To:

```
PlotMarker(json[i].lat, json[i].lng);
```

I think it's because of the outer []'s.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not seem to help. I have edited the question with the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that `getLocations()` is called before `initialize()` is started. You have to comment out `getLocations();` and move it to the end of `initialize()` function.

That is not enough: `map` definition has to be moved outside of `initialize()` function and should not be redefined inside `initialize()` function.

`markerLocations`, used in `PlotMarker()`, is not defined. Should be defined as global like `map`

```
var map;
var markerLocations = [];

function initialize() {
    ...
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
        zoom: 13,
        center: latLng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
    ...
    getLocations();
}
```

`PlotMarker()` has to be called like:

```
PlotMarker(entry.lat, entry.lng);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you ever calling your initialize function? Call it right when the page loads.

```
google.maps.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

as shown [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#HelloWorld).

Answer (score 0):

What is the sequence of those functions? Which do you call first, and next?

I have encountered this kind of problem and what happens is, the map has not finished loading all the tiles so the markers could not be placed on those and so they do not appear. But when you check in the console, the marker objects are there.

This is how I solved it:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'tilesloaded', function() {
    plotMarkers();
    google.maps.event.clearListeners(map, 'tilesloaded');
});
```

It assures the map tiles are completely loaded before plotting the markers. In this case, the markers will surely be visible.